# Primefaces CKEditor wrong URL encoding

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I tried to start using Primefaces CKEditor in my project. I did all what is described here:
https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Getting-Started
But unfortunately the script of CKEditor contains wrong generated urls.

(there some urls is prefixed by '.2')

for example:

insted of:

```
javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/.2editor.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=6.2.5&v=6.2
```

should be

```
javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=6.2.5&v=6.2
```

the same here:

instead of:

```
javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/styles.js.2.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=6.2.5&v=6.2
```

should be

```
javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/styles.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=6.2.5&v=6.2
```

bellow I attach print screen from console. I tried everything that comes to my mind but I not found solution. Meaby someone of you have some Idea or suggestions?

[image]

Comment: That definitely does not look right. Can you add details to your post like what JDK version, what PrimeFaces version, what container and version (Jboss, Payara, etc).   Are you using it it portlets?

Comment: The demo app here everything looks OK: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/customToolbar.jsf and what is really strange is why its attaching two versions to your URL v=6.2.5&v=6.2 when it should only be appending v=6.2.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592500/error-adding-ckeditor-of-primefaces-extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug so it has been reported to the [PFE GitHub page](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/600).

There is a patched 6.2.7.jar in that link that fixes the problem.

This is fixed in PFE 6.2.8+. Thanks for reporting!