# Error adding CKEditor of Primefaces Extensions

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

I am trying to incorporate CKEditor (Primefaces Extensions) to my project to replace p:editor. The problem is that when loading the page shows the following error in the browser console:

Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "default" was not found at "http://localhost:8080/proyecto/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/styles.js.2.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=6.2&v=6.2".

Should be:
http://localhost:8080/proyecto/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/styles.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=6.2&v=6.2

Instead of (add .2 after styles.js):
http://localhost:8080/proyecto/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/styles.js.2.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=6.2&v=6.2

```
<pe:ckEditor id="editText" widgetVar="editText" value="#{accomunicaciones.correoSeleccionado.cuerpo}">  
    <p:ajax event="save" update="growl"/>  
</pe:ckEditor>
```

That could be happening? Thank you.

Comment: Try the newest version: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.primefaces.extensions%22%20AND%20a%3A%22primefaces-extensions%22

Comment: Hi tandraschko, first I tried with the latest version. Then I put the same version I had of primefaces. Give the same error.

Comment: You should also double check your classpath. As you got the "v=6.2" two times, i think also have PFE two times in your classpath.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334120/primefaces-ckeditor-wrong-url-encoding

Comment: What server and version are you using?  There must be something in common as 2 users have now reported this but I can't reproduce locally or on the showcase?

Comment: Hi, Melloware, I'm using Tomcat 8.5.12. I created a new Java EE 7 project and loading the libraries worked perfectly. My current project is old and although we have been updating libraries, it is developed in Java EE 5. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Hello tandraschko, if I'm not wrong, one is the version of primefaces and the other the version of primefaces-extensions, I do not know if the error can come from there since both parameters have the same name.

Comment: @GrupoIWI you did the right thing starting with a new clean project.  And I think you are right the two versions are correct 6.2 for PF and 6.2.7 for PFE.

Comment: @GerardoRoger I posted below can you go to that ticket and report the results from running that patched JAR with your broken version so I can help debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug so it has been reported to the [PFE GitHub page](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/600).

There is a patched 6.2.7.jar in that link that fixes the problem.

This is fixed in PFE 6.2.8+. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Hello  Melloware. I did it in firefox. The error is this: Error: Original URL: styles.js
Final URL: http://localhost:8080/proyecto/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/styles.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=6.3-SNAPSHOT&v=6.2
Original URL: http://localhost:8080/proyecto/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/ [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "default" was not found at "http://localhost:8080/proyecto/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/styles.js.2.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=6.3-SNAPSHOT&v=6.2".

Comment: OK in that GitHub I created another patch JAR for you to test.  I think I fixed it.